# How could javascript work as desired on chrome and IE, but not FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cross-browser

For some reason my 2 amount recieved inputs show up blank in Firefox, but work correctly in Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Can anyone explain why this is?

http://vbwpublishing.com/calcpage.php

also bonus points to anyone who can tell me why the hardcover calculator will allow me to put more than 1200 pages when it should be throwing an error

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: I don't know, but it says error in 3 of the fields if you click home and then click back in the browser

Comment: your also getting this error in chrome:
Uncaught Cannot continue until a pending callback completes.

Comment: Please post code instead of a link when asking a question. This way the answers may be helpful to others even when your website is not available anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your FF javascript console (shift-ctrl-J):

```
scd1 is not defined   http://vbwpublishing.com/calcpage.php    Line: 403
```

which is

```
if ($(scd1).hasClass('s')){sd = .25}
```

You're not executing that in a .ready() block, and the `<li>` with that ID is farther down the page, so it's not defined yet that point, killing the rest of the script execution.

Comment: I wasn't calling the elements correctly. it should have called that element like ('#scd1') instead of just (scd1). Thanks for pointing out where my problem was.